Is there a way in Mono.Cecil to determine that a MethodDefinition is actually a C# operator without parsing the name?
I want to avoid parsing the name, like op_Equality. Is there another way to determine if the given MethodDefinition is actually an operator?

Not that I am aware of;
Section I.10.3 of ECMA-335 states:
Operator overloading is described by using the names specified below, and by setting a special
bit in the metadata (SpecialName) so that they do not collide with the user’s name space. A
CLS-compliant producer tool shall provide some means for setting this bit. If these names are
used, they shall have precisely the semantics described here

followed by a list of such special names (for instance for binary operators ).
That said, since all operators need to be marked as specialname it is possible to quick check whether a method definition may be an operator.

IsSpecialName would also return true for property accessor and event add/remove methods. So just checking for the special name flag is not enough. But I got my answer - thank you.

Indeed, that is why I used "may be an operator"... you still need to check the name anyway
